# Python - Where should a library store temporary files?

Tags: python, package, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I'm writing a Python library which needs to cache remote data on the local machine.

I would like to prevent the library from polluting the OS and placing temp files where they don't belong. To use OS default temp folders seems a bit long winded as I would like to use one OS-Independent way of doing this.

Would storing cached files within the package folder work? Does the Python installation have a folder for temp files?

Help would be great! :)

Comment: If the cache needs to survive reboots, then the files are not temporary. Instead, you could look into http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs for a cross-platform `user_cache_dir` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using `tempfile`, see http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html

Comment: Yes it will. But you need not worry about it, since all temp files will be removed(specific to the user's operating system, on reboot, or at interval). And each time you call it, it will give you another distinct filepath, there will be no collisions.

Comment: if you create a tempfile.TemporaryFile object it will be automatically destroyed for you when it is closed (both explicitly and implicitly). If you use tempfile.mkstemp, you will be responsible for deleting the temp file. If you use tempfile.mkdtemp to create a temp directory to store all your file, you will be responsible for deleting that directory

Comment: @ftartaggia I didn't know the `TemporayFile` object, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @qiao if you are interested, tempfile module also defines NamedTemporaryFile and SpooledTemporaryFile (temp file is stored only in memory until its size exceeds a certain threshold or its fileno() method is invoked)

Comment: @ftartaggia Good to know that. I'm gonna take a deeper look at the documents. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I need to re-access the file in the future though. Can this be done with tempfile module?

Comment: @RadiantHex Are you saying you need a _permanent_ cache? That is not an application for _temporary_ files.

Answer (score 1):

The default answer is to use `tempfile`; if you are using some other cross-platform toolkit, there might be other abstracted ways of achieving the same, for example in PyQt/PySide you have [QtCore.QTemporaryFile](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtemporaryfile.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also consider giving the possibility to the user to specify how your library should handle temp files or where to store them